# Javascript error on action buttons in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript

While editing a survey, or reordering columns for Shared Docs in SharePoint 2013, we are experiencing issues where the "OK" or "FINISH" buttons do nothing.  Looking at developer tools (F12), we see a javascript error.

> Survey:  Unable to set property 'action' of undefined or null
>   reference. Column Reordering: Unable to get property "ReorderedFields'
>   of undefined or null reference.

We have used IE10 and Chrome, but both give the same errors.  Has anyone had this same problem?  If so, how did you resolve it?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like this is custom Javascript that is trying a nonexistent field/variable (did you guys change the name of a column?). Best bet is to have a look at the code it's self and see what it is doing just before it errors.

Comment: We are not changing the name of any columns - just going into the "reorder columns" function and moving a column from position 9 to position 4.

Comment: Once again your best bet is to have a look at the JS code to see what it is doing. As it seems like custom JS there is nothing we can do about it with out the code